# Why this query behaves different on two different machines?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

This fulltext search query returns 10 results on my local environment

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE MATCH ( Field1, Field2, Field3) 
AGAINST ('"longword1 longword2"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

On test environment, with the same data, returns nothing. Why this is behaving weird on test environment?

Table is innoDB and both servers are mysql 5.6

Comment: can you try `SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE MATCH ( Field1, Field2, Field3) AGAINST ('\"word\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` It should work in both environemnts

Comment: @sarvesh: I don't want the double quotes to be part of the matched text. Double quotes are there to find a perfect match in case of multiple words

Comment: Might be because of different configs (innodb_ft_min_token_size) or different stopword lists.

Comment: @piotrm: how do I check that? I tested with words with bigger length though

Comment: perhaps the word `two` is a stop word in one environment

Comment: Check things mentioned in fulltext fine-tuning [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Comment: I'll be checking everything, this is very frustrating. Is there anyway to check all configuration by query? Right now I don't have access to that server

Comment: You can try `SHOW variables LIKE 'innodb_ft%'`

Comment: Configurations returned by `SHOW variables LIKE 'innodb_ft%'` are exactly the same on both servers

Comment: Then maybe try rebuilding fulltext indexes. Other than that I have no idea why the results are different.